# Как посмотреть статистику Telegram бота?

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

Как я могу посмотреть статистику своего Telegram бота?

Использую библиотеку `aiogram`. Нужна статистика вида:

- Количество пользователей за сегодня - 1;
- Количество пользователей в боте - 10;
- Дата - сегодняшняя дата;
- Дата создания бота - дата создания бота (напишу сам).

Comment: чтобы смотреть статистику чего-то надо это что-то куда-то сохранять

Answer (score 0):

Вот код для подсчета пользователей в боте.

database.py

```
from typing import Union

import asyncpg

from asyncpg import Connection
from asyncpg.pool import Pool

class Database:

    def __init__(self):
        self.pool: Union[Pool, None] = None

    async def create(self):
        self.pool = await asyncpg.create_pool(
            user=config.DB_USER,
            password=config.DB_PASS,
            host=config.DB_HOST,
            database=config.DB_NAME
        )

    async def execute(self, command, *args,
                      fetch: bool = False,
                      fetchval: bool = False,
                      fetchrow: bool = False,
                      execute: bool = False
                      ):
        async with self.pool.acquire() as connection:
            connection: Connection
            async with connection.transaction():
                if fetch:
                    result = await connection.fetch(command, *args)
                elif fetchval:
                    result = await connection.fetchval(command, *args)
                elif fetchrow:
                    result = await connection.fetchrow(command, *args)
                elif execute:
                    result = await connection.execute(command, *args)
            return result
        async def create_table_users(self):
             sql = """
             CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Users (
             id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
             full_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
             username varchar(255) NULL
        );
        """
    async def add_user_Users(self, full_name, username):
          sql = '''INSERT INTO users (full_name, username)
                   VALUES($1, $2) returning *'''
          return await self.execute(sql, full_name, username, fetchrow=True)

        await self.execute(sql, execute=True)

    async def select_all_users(self):
        sql = "SELECT * FROM Users"
        return await self.execute(sql, fetch=True)

    async def select_all_users_id(self):
        sql = "SELECT telegram_id FROM Users"
        return await self.execute(sql, fetch=True)

    async def select_user(self, **kwargs):
        sql = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE "
        sql, parameters = self.format_args(sql, parameters=kwargs)
        return await self.execute(sql, *parameters, fetchrow=True)

    async def count_users(self):
        sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users"
        return await self.execute(sql, fetchval=True)
```

config.py

```
DB_USER = env.str('DB_USER')  # Имя пользователя db
DB_PASS = env.str('DB_PASS')  # Пароль от db
DB_HOST = env.str('DB_HOST')
DB_NAME = env.str('DB_NAME')  # Название db
```

start.py

```
@dp.message_handler(CommandStart())
async def register_user(message: types.Message):
    try:
        user = await db.add_user_Users(telegram_id=message.from_user.id,
                                 full_name=message.from_user.full_name,
                                 username=message.from_user.username)
    except asyncpg.exceptions.UniqueViolationError:
        user = await db.select_user(telegram_id=message.from_user.id)

    count = await db.count_users()

    # Забираем как список или как словарь
    user_data = list(user)
    user_data_dict = dict(user)

    # Забираем напрямую как из списка или словаря
    username = user.get("username")
    full_name = user[2]

        await message.answer(
        "\n".join(
            [
                f'Привет, {message.from_user.full_name}!',
                f'В базе <b>{count}</b> пользователей'
            ]))
```

---

PS Использую PostgreSQL, Pythyon 3.8+ (может и будет работать на 3.7, но не проверял), asyncpg.

Answer (score -2):

Обычно для этого используют базу данных. Так как Вы - новичок, легче буде освоить SQLite. Посмотрите это [видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yBEz6TjFKKw), оно должно вам помочь. Если возникнут вопросы, то пишите их в комментариях под этим ответом.